# Handle POST data using Dart Route after already listening to stream

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-async

I am using [route](https://github.com/dart-lang/route) to handle http requests to my server. This is my current route code:

```dart
HttpServer.bind("127.0.0.1", 8080).then((server) {
    new Router(server)
    ..filter(new RegExp(r'/.*'), addCorsHeaders)
    ..filter(new RegExp(r'/admin/.*'), authenticate)
    ..serve(userGetURL, method: 'GET').listen(userGetHandler)
    ..serve(userPostURL, method: 'POST').listen(userPostHandler);
});
```

I am trying to get JSON data that I am POSTing to a URL. The data will be used to get an entity from the database and return it as JSON to the caller. I am basically trying to create a server application that will handle all the data and a client application that will display it.

I cannot figure out how to get the data from a POST. Everything I have tried requires that I listen to the stream, but it is already being listened to. This is how I have been trying to get the POST data:

```dart
userPostHandler(HttpRequest req) {
    req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
        // Return the data back to the client.
        res.write(new String.fromCharCodes(buffer));
        res.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is I get a `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.` error.

**EDIT:** The filters

```dart
Future<bool> authenticate(HttpRequest req) {
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    // Post data is not null
    // Authenticate user
    String userName = '';
    String password = '';
    User user = new User();
    user.DBConnect().then((User user) {
      return new Future.value(user.ValidateUser(userName, password));
    });
  }
}

Future<bool> addCorsHeaders(HttpRequest req) {
  print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');
  req.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*, ');
  req.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS, GET');
  req.response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  return new Future.value(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it runs without an error. `asBroadcastStream()` was not necessary.

Comment: I guess you are also listening in your one of your filter handlers.

Comment: The niether filter has `listen`s in it. I thought that `..serve(..).listen(userPostHandler)` was causing the problem. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes but as it seems because somewhere else is already listening.  
I couldn't get `asBroadcastStream()` working. Your error is only reproducible when I also add a listener to a filter handler.

Comment: I added the filters I am using. I am not sure if anything in there as an implicit listener. Any insights?

Comment: I can't see any problem in your added code. I think it would be best to report this as bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code I was able to get a POST working:

```dart
void main() {
    HttpServer.bind("127.0.0.1", 8080).then((server) {
        new Router(server)
        ..filter(new RegExp(r'/.*'), addCorsHeaders)
          ..filter(new RegExp(r'/admin/.*'), authenticate)
           ..serve(userGetURL, method: 'GET').listen(userGetHandler)
            ..serve(userPostURL, method: 'POST').listen(userPostHandler);
    }); 
}

Future userPostHandler(HttpRequest req) {
  bool headerSent = false;
  // Start listening before writing to the response.
  req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
    if (!headerSent) {
      req.response.write("User POST");
      headerSent = true;
    }
    req.response.write(new String.fromCharCodes(buffer));
    },
    // Use onDone to close the response.
    onDone: () => req.response.close()
  );
}
```

Here is what I figured out. Any write to the response automatically drains the body and thus destroy the POST data. As mentioned [here](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_io/HttpRequest.html#response). Also, listening to the response is done asynchronously and thus must be completed before close() is called.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the Route package but I wonder why you want to listen inside the Handler. Can't you just access the properties you want to process?

Otherwise you could try

```dart
req.asBroadcastStream().listen(...)
```

A BroadcastStream supports multiple listeners.
More information in this article [Use Streams for Data](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/)

Comment: How would I access the properties I want, can you give an example?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want to achieve? Your example `(req.listen((List<int> buffer) ...` isn't very helpful as I can't see what `res.` refers to and I wonder if `listen()` really provides a `List<int>`. If you just want to create the response take a look at https://github.com/dart-lang/route/blob/master/example/server.dart

Comment: I added a paragraph to my question explaining what I am trying to do. I want the client app to POST the ID of an object to the server app and the server app will return that object to the client app.